# How can I set Stream Analytics Output as Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-stream-analytics

How can I add Stored Procedure as Analytics Output 
More simply how can I send my analytics result to sp parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I send my analytics result to sp parameter

If you’d like to pass Stream Analytics jobs result to a Stored Procedure in SQL Database, it seems that there are no direct way to pass analytics result to Stored Procedure and execute the Stored Procedure.

Stream Analytics jobs could [write result to an existing table in an Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#sql-database), you could try to create a [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql#examples) and query result from table and execute Stored Procedure with analytics result, which might be a possible solution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytesttrigger  
ON [dbo].[TableName]
AFTER INSERT   
AS  
   --query the result 

   --execute SP

   EXEC [dbo].[SP name] @para1 = 'val1', @para2 = 'val2';
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with an Azure Function that is triggered by the Azure Stream Analytics Job (HTTP Trigger). The Azure Function then calls the Stored Procedure and passes the ASA output as payload.