# Input-Output: How to use input lookup table also as an output table for update data?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Is there anyway to do insert or update in stream analytics output

Eg. In stream analytics query i need to first check lookup data, if any match found then update table which is used for lookup data. if there is no any match then insert data in same table.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

The **upsert** requirements can't be implemented on the ASA side,you need to try to implement it on the SQL server side instead.

My idea:

1.Create a temporary table to accept the data from ASA output.

2.Create a [AFTER Insert Trigger](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/insert_trigger_performance) to judge if the data exists in the specific and jump into the different branches. Or do the `upsert` with Stored Procedure.

Please refer to this case:[How can I set Stream Analytics Output as Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026676/how-can-i-set-stream-analytics-output-as-stored-procedure)